# Get row wise sum considering all the previous sums in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sum, cumulative-sum, rowwise

Tried to get row wise sum considering all the previous sums and got output shown below.

Can please anybody tell me what i'm missing?

```
SELECT
  ProductId,
  ProductName,
  ProductAmount As ProductActualAmount,
  CASE
    WHEN (CASE
        WHEN LEAD(ProductAmount) OVER (ORDER BY ProductId) IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE LEAD(ProductAmount) OVER (ORDER BY ProductId)
      END) != 0.00 THEN (ProductAmount + CASE
        WHEN LAG(ProductAmount) OVER (ORDER BY ProductId) IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE LAG(ProductAmount) OVER (ORDER BY ProductId)
      END)
    ELSE (CASE
        WHEN LEAD(ProductAmount) OVER (ORDER BY ProductId) IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE LEAD(ProductAmount) OVER (ORDER BY ProductId)
      END)
  END AS SumAmount
FROM ProductSales
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Expected Output:**

```
ProductId   ProductName   ProductActualAmount   SumAmount
---------------------------------------------------------
1           Rexona        35.00                 35.00
2           Liril         40.00                 75.00
3           Dove          45.00                 120.00         
4           Pears         50.00                 170.00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `SUM() OVER` will give your expected result:

```
SELECT ProductId, 
       ProductName,
       ProductAmount AS ProductActualAmount,
       SUM(ProductAmount) OVER (ORDER BY ProductId) AS SumAmount
FROM ProductSales
```

[**Demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9544f9c49a1ba130d15ae9ab70881369)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a correlated subquery as

```
SELECT ProductId, 
       ProductName, 
       ProductAmount AS ProductActualAmount,
       (
         SELECT SUM(PS2.ProductAmount)
         FROM ProductSales PS2
         WHERE PS1.ProductAmount >= PS2.ProductAmount 
       ) SumAmount
FROM ProductSales PS1;
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=407cdb04506869aecf737e2dc8db4cb6)**